# Hiding rest of article before form is filled

Tags: javascript, html, blogs

I am currently building the blog and the client asked me to create a modal after a few scrolls so the user has to submit the email before continuing with reading.

I have built that. No problem.

**BUT** now he asked me if there is a way to prevent the user to see the rest of the content in Inspector or not just by disabling overflow:hidden on the body.

So is there any way to hide the rest of the content from the inspector before hitting the submit button?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: If you want to prevent the user to see the rest of the content in Inspector, try displaying only part of the content. Say first 50 characters. And have a logic to display the entire content when user is eligible to see the content.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is have the submit button run a function that sets a global variable `ishidden`from a default true to false.

The code for `ishidden` might look like this:

```
var ishidden = false;

//function that makes the user do form -> sets ishidden to true

//submit form function -> sets ishidden to false
```

and then you would have an `if` function that would change the styling

that might look like this:

```
//pure js solution. jquery is a bit different
if(ishidden){
  document.getElementById(article).style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

there would be a bit more code, but this is the general idea